# How do I prevent repetition in a character argument in a list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, character

I'm working on a little game for a school project. The player, supposedly, can pick from a list of characters (the picked characters I'm going to put into an array later on), and each of them can have a name consisting of only a single character.

I placed the character pool in an ArrayList but I don't know how to prevent them from having repeating letters as names.

```
ArrayList<Character> names = new ArrayList<Character>();   

        while (names.size() < 10) {
            char random = (char) ((char) rand.nextInt(26)+'A');
            if (!names.contains(random)) {
                names.add(random);
            }
        }  

ArrayList<Person> charpool = new ArrayList<Person>();

        while (charpool.size() < 10){
            charpool.add(new Person(names.get(rand.nextInt(10)), 
                        (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), 
                        (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), 
                        (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), 
                        (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), 
                        (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), 
                        true, (r1.nextInt(100)+1), 1));
        }
```

Don't mind the insanely long list of int variables, it's for random skills. It probably could be prettier but at this point I just don't care.

I'm rather new to this whole Java thing, and I haven't worked with lists or anything similar before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to have an unique character for each person, when you are filling the `ArrayList<Person> charpool`.

What you could do is remove the character from `names`, once you used it.

```
while(charpool.size() < 10) {
    int index = rand.nextInt(names.size()); //Use names.size() since the names ArrayList will get smaller each iteration
    charpool.add(new Person(names.get(index), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), (r1.nextInt(100)+1), true, (r1.nextInt(100)+1), 1));
    names.remove(index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick save!
I figured the solution would be easy, but like I said, I'm quite a beginner.